# How to retrieve variable branch after using makeBranch

Tags: cplex

I used makeBranch to create branch on specific variables at each node. Before using makeBranch i used NodeCallback to retrieve which variable is selected for branching. 
Now when I use makeBranch, NodeCallback doesn’t show any information about variable branch. How can i control and show that the variable i specified is selected for branching? As well as it didn’t show any record in Cplex(Concert C++) consul log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify a custom branch via the branch callback then CPLEX will perform exactly the branching that you specified. There is no need to double check that.

In order to find the branching decisions at a particular node it is better to store them as node user data in the node. The `makeBranch` function has overloads that allow setting a user object for each newly created branch. Store the branching decision in this user data object. Then, at any node, use the callback's `getNodeData()` function to retrieve the user data at the current node.